# Sails JS: unit testing common server bootstrap file

Tags: express, mocha.js, sails.js

I'm using Mocha (along with supertest, should, etc...)

I'm testing the following controllers and models (example):
Controller1, Controller2, Model1, Model2.

I save my tests under

- ./tests/controller/controller1.js
- ./tests/controller/controller2.js
- ./tests/model/model1.js
- ./tests/model/model2.js

**Problem: **

In each test file, I am using **before()** to bootstrap the sails server, along with other configuration.

But I have the feeling that this is not a good practice, as I don't want to bootstrap the server in each test file, there must be a ./test/bootstrap.js file that shares the server between other tests.

**How to do this?**

**Is it a good practice or should I stay with the current implementation?**

Answer (score 1):

This practice is fine.  It's how we do a lot of the [core Sails integration tests](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/test/integration)!  Just make sure you lower the Sails instance after your tests run, in an `after()` method.  You may also want to abstract the server lifting code into a helper file if you find yourself using a common set of configuration options to the `lift` function.

Comment: "This practice is fine", "this" refers to? lifting sails before each test file? if you mean lift it once for all the tests, how do i do this? i don't see the code has a common sails lifter. how do I tell Mocha to use ./tests/bootstrap.js to lift the sails before all the tests runs and lower it after they finish?

Comment: Your current practice of lifting Sails before each test suite is fine.  Trying to implement a solution that will work across multiple test files is more problematic than it's worth; you're much better off starting with a clean server state for each suite or, in some cases, for each individual test.  The core integration tests use the `appHelper.js` library mostly for building the test app (which is only relevant for core tests), but also for lifting Sails with some default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I know this comes late, but I was also struggling with this as having numerous tests suites in my application means the time spend on lifting lowering the application was added for every suite and increased the total time spend of the tests.

However I found out that if I lifted the application in the first suite in this manner:

```
before(function(done) {
    Sails.lift({}, function (err, server) {
      if (err) throw err; // or handle it
      sails = server;
      dbInitStuff(function callback() {
        done(null, sails);
      });
    });
  });
```

and in the after I did not lower the sails:

```
after(function(done) {
    //sails.lower(done);
    done();
  });
```

when the code reached the second suite it recognized a global 'sails' variable which was a reference to the sails initialized in the first suite and which held the same state. I was able to run the tests and go on in this manner until the last suite where I lowered the sails.

Probably not a good practice, but it did the trick in my case.